# how can I test react native components that includes PNGs images with Jest

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

As I have tested my application which has navigation that has png images in node modules but tests are failing.

**Source codes of App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {styles} from './src/assets/styles';
import {AppStack} from './src/components/navs/stacks/AppStack';

const App = () => {
  //TODO: Designing ui for spend and scheduled :progress
  // doing list of data from utils/index.js :done
  //fech those data to screen that needs them
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.app}>
      <AppStack />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**App-test.js**

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

**Expected Result:**
Test should render my App entry point which is is **App.js**
**Actual Result**

```
Janviers-MacBook-Pro:credex janvier$ npm test

> credex@0.0.1 test
> jest

 FAIL  __tests__/App-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Volumes/D/Coding/credex/node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/commonjs/assets/back-icon.png:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){�PNG
                                                                                             

    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/commonjs/index.tsx:20:3)
```

Answer (score 5):

Reason for the error is Jest failing to interpret the binary code of .png file (or any image file) into .js.

The solution or rather the way around is to mock a default response whenever Jest encounters an image file.

Steps:

1. Create a file named ImageMock.js (.tsx if you're using TypeScript) in a folder named `__mock__` (or any name).

`YourApp/__mock__/ImageMock.js`

2. Write `export default '';` in ImageMock.js
3. Add `moduleNameMapper` key with the below value within the `jest` key in package.json

```
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(png|jpg|ico|jpeg|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mock__/ImageMock.js"
  }
}
```

NB: Only the png in the moduleNameMapper key value is required for your particular error.